# Multiple methods of inputting files

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

What is the difference between the following commands:

```
$ input.txt > grep foo

$ grep foo < input.txt

$ cat input.txt | grep foo

$ grep foo input.txt
```

And not just `grep`. Other commands too.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/117549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `input.txt > grep foo`  This is probably an error. It runs the *command* `input.txt` and redirects the output to a file called `grep`. The `foo` is an argument to the command `input.txt`.
2. `grep foo < input.txt`  This looks for the string `foo` in the input coming from `input.txt`.  `grep` does not get a filename on the command line, so it will work on standard input instead.  The shell will, through the redirection, ensure that the contents of the file `input.txt` is delivered on the standard input stream for `grep`.
3. `cat input.txt | grep foo`   This is similar to the previous, but the standard input stream of `grep` is now connected to a pipe through which the `cat` command delivers the contents of the file `input.txt`. The `cat` command writes to its standard output stream, which is connected to the standard input stream of `grep` by the pipe.
4. `grep foo input.txt`  This makes `grep` open the file `input.txt` and look for the string `foo` in it. It does not use the standard input stream.

In general:

- A pipe (`|`) connects the standard output stream of its left side with the standard input stream of its right side.
- A input redirection (`<`) redirects from a file to the standard input stream.
- An output redirection (`>`) redirects the standard output to a file.
- Input and output streams may be redirected at the same time, e.g. using `commandname <inputfile >outputfile`, and a command may both read and write to a pipe, as the second command in `command1 | command2 | command3`.
- Redirection and piping may be combined: `cat <input.txt | grep foo >output.txt`.

Many Unix utilities takes an input filename as an optional argument, and will use standard input if no filename was given.

Some Unix utilities *only* works on standard input, like `tr` for example.

Bash and some other shells, like `ksh`, also supports redirection from a string to standard input using `<<<"string"` (called a *here-string*), and most shells understands *here-documents* (look these up).

Comment: Is it possible to input and output to a file using redirection? Eg: `input.txt > grep foo > output.txt?` or `grep foo < input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: @vikarjramun Yes, definitely. Use `commandname >outputfile <inputfile` or `commandname <inputfile >outputfile`.  The first word on the command line will always be interpreted as a command, so `inputfile >commandname` won't work.