# How to a grep a word from a file and store it into another existing file?

Tags: grep

How to a grep a word from a file and store it into another existing file?

What I've tried is

```
cat q1.txt | grep -i "osx" test.txt
```

I want to grep it from test.txt and store it into q1, but this and the other way around doesn't work

Answer (score 13):

You may drop the `cat` completely, and then you should redirect the output from `grep` to the result file:

```
grep -i "osx" test.txt >q1.txt
```

This will search for lines in `test.txt` containing the string `osx` (case-insensitively), and store those lines in `q1.txt`.  If the file `q1.txt` exists, it will be truncated (emptied) before the output is stored in it.

If you wish to append the output at the end of the file, use `>>` rather than `>` as the redirection operator.

---

Your command:

```
cat q1.txt | grep -i "osx" test.txt
```

What this actually does is to start `cat` and `grep` concurrently.  `cat` will read from `q1.txt` and try to write it to its standard output, which is connected to the standard input of `grep`.

However, since you're giving `grep` a file to read from, it will totally ignore whatever `cat` is sending it.

In the end, all lines in `test.txt` that contains the string `osx` will be outputted to the terminal.

---

There is something often referred to as "useless use of `cat`" (or sometimes "UUoC"), which means that a `cat` invocation may be completely removed and that the file may instead be read directly by another tool.

The extreme example of that would be:

```
cat test.txt | cat | cat | cat | grep -i "osx" | cat | cat >q1.txt
```

but even just

```
cat test.txt | grep -i "osx" >q1.txt
```

is useless as `grep` is perfectly capable of reading from a file by itself (as seen above). Even if it *wasn't* able to open `test.txt` by itself, one could have written

```
grep -i "osx" <test.txt >q1.txt
```

to say that standard input should come from the `test.txt` file and that standard output should go to the `q1.txt` file

Use `cat` only when concatenating data (that's what its main use is). There are a few other uses of `cat` too, but it's outside the scope of this question.

---

Related:

- [Multiple methods of inputting files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305454/multiple-methods-of-inputting-files)
- [How is this command legal? "> file1 < file2 cat"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356118/how-is-this-command-legal-file1-file2-cat)

Comment: It's a personal preferrence, but I would like to see a space around redirection symbol.

Comment: @Vlastimil Yes, that's a personal preference. I tend to not put a space in-between them since they "belong together".  The POSIX standards document on redirection also does not put a space in-between: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07

Answer (score -1):

For searching in a file and writing the result in "path/storage_file":

```
grep -in pattern file > path/storage_file
```

For searching in a file and appending (use >>) the result in "path/storage_file":

```
grep -in pattern file >> path/storage_file
```

For searching in an entire directory and writing the result in "path/storage_file":

```
grep -in pattern * > path/storage_file
```

For searching in an entire directory and appending (use >>) the result in "path/storage_file":

```
grep -in pattern * >> path/storage_file
```

Comment: Do you know what the `-in` does?

Comment: Good examples, but be aware that using the `n` flag will prepend the line number to each resulting line.